# Class Level Variable Eligible for GC in Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have an Employee, an Organization and Test class. The employee contains information related to Employee and Organization class contains Employee list. Please find below source code of both class:

> Employee.java

```
package com.practice;

public class Employee {
private String empId;
private String name;
private int age;
private float salary;

public Employee(final String empId, final String name, final int age, final float salary) {
    this.empId = empId;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

public void setEmpId(final String empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(final int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public float getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(final float salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.empId + " " + this.name + " " + this.age + " " + this.salary;
}
}
```

> Organization.java

```
package com.practice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Organization {

private final List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

Organization() {

}

public void addEmployee(final Employee emp) {
    this.empList.add(emp);
}

public List<Employee> getEmpList() {
    return empList;
}

}
```

> TestGC.java

```
package com.practice;

public class TestGC {

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Employee emp = new Employee("E1", "Emp 1", 20, 2000.0f);
    final Employee emp2 = new Employee("E1", "Emp 1", 20, 2000.0f);

    final Organization org = new Organization();
    org.addEmployee(emp);
    org.addEmployee(emp2);

    System.out.println(org.getEmpList());
}

}
```

In Organization.java, we have list of Employee object and I have created the object in the same line, that means at class level. So, my question is, will that list be eligible for GC once I'm done with Organization object or it will be a leak in memory? Also, will it make any difference if I instantiate the same object inside constructor?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean class level (i.e. static). It's a normal instance variable.

Comment: No memory leak, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you have are regular instance variables (as well as a few local variables). They will be collected normally, when they're no longer reachable. It makes no difference if you instantiate them from the constructors, it'll only add unnecessary code.

It's not *that* easy to leak memory in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> Will that list be eligible for GC once I'm done with Organization
>   object or it will be a leak in memory?

Yes. List will be eligible for the GC once `organization` object goes out of scope. All you are using are instance variables, so no need to worry about memory leak unless you have some static variables used in bad way.

> will it make any difference if I instantiate the same object inside
>   constructor?

No.